# Boxes appearing underneath footer. Require above

Tags: html, css

I have some div containers which expand when the 'view recipe button is clicked, but all 3 across the bottom will hide underneath the footer container, i'm unsure which element to alter to have the expanded containers appear above and not underneath.

live url: http://bit.ly/1hQuzRI

I've attached the css of the elements which are appearing underneath the footer and some from the footer too. I can paste the html but there is loads which will end up showing up. maybe best to just view direct on site.

```
.box2-container-collapsed {
padding: 10px; 
width: 270px;
height: auto;
background-color: #F5F2E9;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
}


.box2-content {
margin-left: 0px;
font-size: 0.9em;
min-height: 200px;
display: none;
}

#footer {
background-color: #F3F3F3;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
bottom: 0;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Found it, and tested with Chrome Dev tools to make sure it was actually the problem.  Remove overflow:hidden from the class content-container.

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index in the footer to a negative number.  Also try setting the z-index for the div that expands to a higher number.

**Edit**:
Your div with the class="content-container" has overflow:hidden.  I removed that in my Chrome-Dev tools and the expanding div was visible after that.  Side Note:  It's difficult to see where the recipe ends and the footer begins.  You may want to put a light border around the recipe div, too.

Comment: Gave that a shot too but still nothing.

Comment: You have overflow:hidden on your content-container, and the expanding div extends outside of it.